# converting excel scientific notation to original numbers

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I have imported some query results from SQL Server 2008 to Excel csv file and it got imported like the following:

[image]

So `Acct_No` and `TELE` looks similar. How can I make sure that everything gets displayed uniquely? These scientific notation is making everything look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to text.  Since it's an account number there is no need to calculate it and therefore no need to treat it as a number.  When you import delimited files, make sure to specify that column not as "general", but as text.

If the file is already created, use the "text to columns" functionality.

Edit:  For example:  [office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-names-by-using-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-HA010102340.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-names-by-using-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-HA010102340.aspx)

Comment: When I did `Format Cells -> Number --> Text`, it didn't result in any thing new change except that the stuff got left aligned. Are you saying when I import delimited files from SQL Server? I just used Save as option there.

Comment: That's not the same thing, but close.  You'll  find that if you click into each cell and then hit enter the cell will have a green triangle in the corner, this means it is a number saved as text, and (in my opinion) what you want.  It won't become a scientific notation because it is text.  Formatting as you described means that you have to go one by one, entering the cells and accepting the values.  Using the "text to columns" tool converts every cell without further ado.

Answer (score 1):

Click on both columns and:

Format > Format Cells... > Number > Number > and specify no decimals

and if you prefer macros:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:B").Cells.NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't works. When I save it and open the file ,it opens up with the same format.